# sending push notification to a specified tag with azure notification hub not working

Tags: c#, azure, azure-notificationhub

I am not able to send notification to my device when I specify a tag to send notification. I am able to send notification when I do not specify any tag or with simple tags like "allDevice", "girls" etc. But when I use format like "username:myname.surname@mycompany.net" it s not sending notification. I am trying both with notification hub c# library or in the azure notification hub "send test" section.

Comment: You need to register your device with the same tag to receive the notification, have you done that?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/azure-services/azure-notification-hub

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest verifying the registration stored within Notification Hubs has the expected tags present on it. So manually writing some small console application (some samples here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-dotnet/tree/master/Samples/RegistrationSample) or using something like Service Bus Explorer (https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer - supports Notification Hubs) to list registrations.

From there you should be able to enumerate your registrations and see if the tag is actually stored there. If it's not there, it indicates a problem on the application side sending the tag up.

If you're still having problems, please feel free to open a support case in the Azure Portal and someone from the team can look into your particular issue and logs on our side to determine where things are going wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I resolved the issue. I was able to retrieve my registration via notification hub library but then I realized my registration removed from device list. When I re-register everything worked. Actually microsoft docs not very clear about how to properly register a device. I have logic like retrieve registration by handle, check if registrationId null, if null create new registrationId otherwise update registration. I still do not know if I am able to retrieve registrationId by handle , this registration is valid(?). Is it possible to get registrationId but it expired for example.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to resolve the issue and I'm sorry to hear the docs aren't clear. I'll pass along this feedback to the team and we can work on improvements.

This is the doc I'm most familiar with documenting the flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management

The general pattern we advise is to have the app create a registration and tags every time the application starts. Having multiple registrations for the device is completely ok, and Notification Hubs will automatically dedupe on send.

Comment: It s good to learn notification hub can send notification to correct device even there are duplicate registrations. I am still checking registration with device handle, and create only one registration per device. I am doing this cause there are registration count limits on each notification hub plan. So my client will not be happy if he reach the limit very quick with less user count.